# How to test onKeyPress event handler with Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, testing, enzyme

I've got a test which triggers the onKeyPress event:

```
    const wrapper = mount(wrapper);

    wrapper
      .find('[data-test="test-number-input"]')
      .find("input")
      .simulate("keypress", { target: { value: "2" }, key: 2 });
```

This works fine but does not trigger the onChange event in the component (unlike when run in the browser). To my understanding this behavior is intentional in Enzyme. The problem then is that I cannot read the new value since the state is set in the onChange handler. What would then be the best way to test the behaviour of my keyPress handler?

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export default (props) => {
  const minValue = props.minValue ?? 0;
  const maxValue = props.maxValue ?? 100;
  const step = props.step ?? 1;

  const handleKeyPress = (evt) => {
    const enteredCharCode = evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    const newValue = evt.target.value + evt.key;

    if (
      enteredCharCode <= 47 ||
      enteredCharCode >= 58 ||
      newValue < minValue ||
      newValue > maxValue
    ) {
      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (evt) => {
    if (evt.target.value[0] === "0" && evt.target.value.length > 1) {
      /* Prevent input if the first character is zero and the entered character is also zero.
           else remove the first zero. */
      (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) === 48
        ? evt.preventDefault()
        : (evt.target.value = evt.target.value.slice(1));
    } else {
      props.onChange(evt);
    }
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      name={props.name}
      label={props.labelText}
      type="number"
      defaultValue={props.defaultValue}
      inputProps={{
        min: minValue,
        max: maxValue,
        step: step,
      }}
      onKeyPress={handleKeyPress}
      onChange={handleChange}
      data-test="test-number-input"
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not an ideal solution in my opinion, I decided to follow this https://medium.com/@acesmndr/testing-react-functional-components-with-hooks-using-enzyme-f732124d320a and move the event handler method outside of the component function:

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

export const handleKeyPress = (evt, minValue, maxValue) => {
  const enteredCharCode = evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
  const newValue = evt.target.value + evt.key;

  if (
    enteredCharCode <= 47 ||
    enteredCharCode >= 58 ||
    newValue < minValue ||
    newValue > maxValue
  ) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  return newValue;
};

export default (props) => {
  const minValue = props.minValue ?? 0;
  const maxValue = props.maxValue ?? 100;
  const step = props.step ?? 1;

  const handleChange = (evt) => {
    if (evt.target.value[0] === "0" && evt.target.value.length > 1) {
      /* Prevent input if the first character is zero and the entered character is also zero.
           else remove the first zero. */
      (evt.which ? evt.which : evt.keyCode) === 48
        ? evt.preventDefault()
        : (evt.target.value = evt.target.value.slice(1));
    } else {
      props.onChange(evt);
    }
  };

  return (
    <TextField
      name={props.name}
      label={props.labelText}
      type="number"
      defaultValue={props.defaultValue}
      inputProps={{
        min: minValue,
        max: maxValue,
        step: step,
      }}
      onKeyPress={(evt) => handleKeyPress(evt, minValue, maxValue)}
      onChange={handleChange}
      data-test="test-number-input"
    />
  );
};
```

So now I can test the event handler like this:

```
expect(
      handleKeyPress(
        {
          target: { value: "5" },
          key: 2,
          preventDefault: () => {},
        },
        1,
        100
      )
    ).toBe("52");

    expect(
      handleKeyPress(
        {
          target: { value: "99" },
          key: 2,
          preventDefault: () => {},
        },
        1,
        100
      )
    ).toBe(undefined);
```